# Helper screen on first launch (9-patch)

Tags: android-layout, android, nine-patch

I'm trying to develop a help screen for the first launch of an application. To do that work on all size of device, I have done a 9patch file (Don't look at the design it's totally raw. I just want to make a proof of concept for the designer)

[image]

As you can see, I want to repeat (according the screen size) the left space vertically and the space between "Swipe to" and "you have done" horizontally.

I've put my png in the hdpi folder and my activity contains the following resource layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/helper"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the result with a picture 720px large:
[image: 720px]

Here is the result with a picture 480px large:
[image: 480px portrait]
[image: 480px landscape]

Here is the result with a picture 240px large:
[image: 240px portrait]
[image: 240px landscape]

I think I have to play with a good dimension and ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi folder and maybe also with derivated ldpi-landscap/mdpi-landscape....

Is there a way to do it right ? What dimension should my image have ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question off the top of my head. However, I don't understand why you're making it difficult and using a 9patch image. Can't you split the overlay into 4 images. One is the translucent grey background, and the other three are the different arrows/notes. This way you will be able to centre the bottom bit properly, and layout your images how you wish in all orientations.

Comment: you'll need to create several images with various resolutions to accomodate all screen sizes

Comment: @ThomasClayson because 9-patch are done for this kind of case (extensible area for matching all device size). I suggest you to put your message as answer and I will accept if if there is no solution to my 9-patch file.

Comment: @Hrk Nope, 9patch are for extensible areas, but not to match all device sizes. They're for buttons with variable text, or input areas with variable size, maybe for backgrounds of views that need to stretch. Not for different screen sizes, thats why you have different drawable folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas Clayson suggests, I've done not 4 but 2 images:

- Top: the 2 arrows and corresponding text
- Bottom: the "switch to display" and "tap to dismiss"

Here is my "test" layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/my_translucent_background_color" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/helper_top"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_bottom"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/helper_bottom"
    android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

I still have some issues for the top area when it's resize, it doesn't fit the right top angle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this custom view: [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)

It would do something like what you need to achieve, in an easier, pain-less and more compatible way.

Comment: Thanks, I know this lib, but for now there is no support for action bar button and it's seems quite tricky to implement.